# Qt/embedded logging facility

Tags: qtembedded

I am new to porting qt/embedded to embedded linux.

I want to know about how qt manages logging facility over embedded linux. If the logging facility is there, it can be pushed to serial port or it can be disabled.

Could you anyone share us the view of porting qt to embedded linux and about the logging faciliy? (About what are the real thing that i should consider before porting qt to embedded linux)

Regards,
Santhosh.

Answer (score 0):

For this, i got an answer of disabling the debug log messages.

We should disable the macro's QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT and QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT during compilation process.

Hope, it should help :)